# VBA - Stop the whole script running if condition is not met

Tags: excel, vba

How can I stop the below script running further if the "Else Case" is met as it keeps running further and copies next data from the spreadsheet using similar Dir function next? The data is not being copied from the LatesFile2 workbook however I want to stop the code completely if the first check is not passed

```
    Sub ()
        Dim MyPath2, MyFile2, LatestFile2 As String
        Dim LatestDate2, LMD2 As Date
        Dim lastrow5  As Long
        Dim Today As String
        Dim rng, cell As Range
        Dim ws1 As Worksheet
        Set ws1 = Workbooks("Workbooks").Sheets(1)
        Today = Format(Now(), "YYYYMMDD")
        
          MyPath2 = "\\'directory"
            If Right(MyPath2, 1) <> "\" Then MyPath2 = MyPath2 & "\"
            MyFile2 = Dir(MyPath2 & "'Workbooksname" & "*.xlsx", vbNormal)
            If Len(MyFile2) = 0 Then
                MsgBox "No files were found!", vbExclamation
                Exit Sub
            End If
            Do While Len(MyFile2) > 0
                LMD2 = FileDateTime(MyPath2 & MyFile2)
                If LMD2 > LatestDate2 Then
                    LatestFile2 = MyFile2
                    LatestDate2 = LMD2
                End If
                MyFile2 = Dir
            Loop 
        Workbooks.Open MyPath2 & LatestFile2
        
        lastrow5 = Workbooks(LatestFile2).Sheets(1).Columns("A").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        Set rng = Workbooks(LatestFile2).Sheets(1).Range("A1:A" & lastrow5)
        
        For Each cell In rng
            Select Case Left$(cell.Value, 1)
                Case "E", "S"
            Case Else
                  MsgBox "Bad value in row " 
                    Workbooks(LatestFile2).Close SaveChanges:=False 'and stop the script from executing further if criteria "Case Else" is met!!!
        Exit Sub
        End Select
        Next
        
        Rows("1:1").Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            Selection.AutoFilter
            ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$H$1259").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>S*", _
                Operator:=xlAnd
            Range("A2").Select
            Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
            Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
            Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
            Selection.EntireRow.Delete
            ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$H$429").AutoFilter Field:=1
            Selection.Copy
                ws1.Activate
                   Range("B2").Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
            
            Workbooks(LatestFile2).Activate
            ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

'here is Dir function similar to above with looking for workbook in the folder and opening it
        
End Sub
```

Comment: `Exit Sub` will end execution

Comment: Hi, yes it is supposed to and I have it in the script however it keeps running further!

Comment: Maybe step through with `F8` to see the execution. `Exit Sub` should do just that.

Comment: Do you get the MsgBox ?

Comment: @bigben - F8 gave same result

Comment: Did you get the `MsgBox` as Tim asked?

Comment: @ Tim Tilliams - I do not get the Msgbox, opened workbook gets closed and code is proceeding with the rest part of sub

Comment: That means that `Case Else` was never reached.

Comment: @Bigben but I am testing it with workbook which has only letter "E" in column A in sheet1 , isn't it Case Else if names in column A start only with "E"?

Comment: No, `Case Else` is if they *don't* start with "E".

Comment: @ hmm then it is not exactly what I expect with {Select Case} part, I expect code to return me msgbox if : 1) There is name starting with any other letter than "E", "S"; 2) if column A consists of names starting with one of this letters: if there is only "E" or  only "S". Case should be met only if names in column A start with both of this letters otherwise should get {Case Else}

Comment: `Case "E", "S"` has no actions, so that is a "do nothing" case, and everything else goes to `Case Else`.

Comment: Is there a way to implement criterias from my comment above within code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the revised logic as described in the comment:

```
Dim countE As Long, countS As Long, countTotal As Long

For Each cell In rng
    Select Case Left$(cell.Value, 1)
        Case "E"
            countE = countE + 1
        Case "S"
            countS = countS + 1
    End Select
Next

countTotal = Application.CountA(rng)

If countE = 0 Or countS = 0 Or (countE + countS <> countTotal) Then
    MsgBox "Something fishy here"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

This could be optimized by reading `rng` into an array and looping over it, but I'll leave that to you.